# Reef route movement rules

Tags: kids, reef-route

The kids boardgame, [Reef Route](https://www.publishing.brain-games.com/reef-route), seems to be missing some rules from the [rulebook](https://docs.wixstatic.com/ugd/8fbe28_c787fc8bb6f643eea318c09e92695d7d.pdf). Nothing too serious, but it still bothers me.

In the rules is stated that a small fish gets eaten by a predator when the predator moves to the same space with the smaller fish. It also says that a small fish cannot move to the same space as another small fish, and if the player is unable to move small fishes indicated by the dice, any other small fish can be moved. But I cannot find anything about moving a small fish to the same space with a predator.

So, can a small fish rush head on into the mouth of a predator? In that case one could feed other players fishes in some situations. Intuitively I'd say it shouldn't work like that, but I'd like to get confirmation for it.

Comment: That's the way we played it.  My 6 year old loves it when he gets to send my fish into the Predator.

Comment: @LeppyR64 that's also how we play it, and it's hilarious for my 5 year old daughter. Knowing the official rule won't propably even change that, but I'm too much of a perfectionist (nitpicker) to just let it go. I actually sent feedback for the publisher, lets see if they give me the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I contacted [the publisher](https://www.publishing.brain-games.com/) and got the official rule:

*"In concept, a small fish moving into a square occupied by a predatory fish means the small fish gets eaten."*

So, the small fishes can indeed rush head on into the mouth of a predator. Seems like my daughter can continue feeding my beautiful little fishes to sharks, and there's nothing I can do about it.